# When cloning item select not working

Tags: jquery

I have a button on my website that clones a few textboxes and allows the users to add multiple guests to their booking.

I have 3 textboxes and a fourth which is a select option. For some reason when I run the function `NewMenuItem()` the select option does not work for the newitem, however the original does work.  The select option just is frozen (it shows an option) but dont allow you to click the dropdown.

I have a feeling it is to do with the class being "chosen-select".

```js
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Chosen Plugin
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

var config = {
  '.chosen-select'           : {disable_search_threshold: 10, width:"100%"},
  '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true, width:"100%"},
  '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:100, width:"100%"},
  '.chosen-select-no-single.no-search' : {disable_search_threshold:10, width:"100%"},
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
  '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
};

for (var selector in config) {
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(selector)) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
   }
}


/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* Guest List
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
function newMenuItem() {
  var newElem = $('tr.pricing-list-item.pattern').first().clone();
  newElem.find('input').val('');
  newElem.appendTo('table#pricing-list-container');
}

if ($("table#pricing-list-container").is('*')) {
  $('.add-pricing-list-item').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newMenuItem();
  });

  // remove ingredient
  $(document).on("click", "#pricing-list-container .delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

  // add submenu
  $('.add-pricing-submenu').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var newElem = $('' +
      '<tr class="pricing-list-item pricing-submenu">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<div class="fm-move"><i class="sl sl-icon-cursor-move"></i></div>' +
      '<div class="fm-input"><input type="text" placeholder="Category Title" /></div>' +
      '<div class="fm-close"><a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>');

    newElem.appendTo('table#pricing-list-container');
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pricing-list-container">
  <tr class="pricing-list-item pattern">
    <td>

      <div class="fm-input pricing-name">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" value=""></div>
      <div class="fm-input pricing-name">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" value=""></div>
      <div class="fm-input pricing-name">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" value=""></div>

      <div class="fm-input pricing-name">
        <label>Package</label>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Item" class="chosen-select" id="packages[]">
    <option>Select a package </option>
    
    <option value = "">Package1 </option>
    <option value = "">Package2 </option>
    </select></div>



      <div class="fm-close"><a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" class="button add-pricing-list-item">Add Guest</a>
```

Comment: Your code snippet here _never_ shows those select fields, they stay at `display:none` ... Please create an example that actually matches what you say you’re seeing.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/83rxnno9/ ... but you'll need to remove the `style="display: none"` on you select (As mentioned by CBroe)

Comment: sorry that was cause of the chosen plugin i am using, i've added it into the code, hope this helps.